# In Laravel Getting related data with array of ids. Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

in `CustomerDashboard` in `station_ids` column I'm storing an array of ids.

I don't know how to add a `hasMany()` relation in model for this one

```
$dashboards = CustomDashboard::get();
foreach($dashboards as $board) {
    $stationIds = json_decode($board->station_ids);
    $board['stations'] = Station::select('id', 'station_name')->whereIn('id', $stationIds)->get();
}
```

Comment: why not use join?

Comment: In `CustomDashboard` model > create a function `stations()` which returns: `return $this->hasMany(Station::class)`. See documentation here > https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: `I don't know how to add a hasMany() relation` - bc this is not the relation you have. You need a many to many relation and need to decouple the station_ids field into a pivot table.

Comment: If a station can belong to only one CustomDashboard then it's a hasMany relation. but if each station can be linked to multiple CustomDashboard then it's a belongsToMany (many to many) relation and a pivot table is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here you need a many to many relation
so you have to create a third table

> php artisan make migration:create_customdashboard_station_table

then you need to add that table

```
$table->foreignId('station_id')->constrained('stations');
$table->foreignId('customdashboard_id')->constrained('customdashboards'); // whatever your table name is
```

then you need a relation called belongs to many

so in your station model

```
public function customDashboards(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(CustomDashboard::class,'customdashboard_station');
}
```

and in your Custom dashboard model you have to add the same

```
public function stations(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Station::class,'customdashboard_station');
}
```

now you have a many to many relation and you can get the ids like this :

```
$boardStations = $board->stations->pluck('id')->toArray();
```